# While editing someone's question, how should I improve formatting of such quasi-formula?

Tags: discussion, edits

I think I should improve readability of the piece with the text saying "(Quantity per re-order)*(unit price)" to visually emphasise that this is kind of a pseudo math expression:

[image: A question being edited]

What formatting should I use for such pseudo-code? I know that code backticks are frowned upon to use in such case, but I can't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any value gained from changing the formatting on that.  It's plenty clear enough since it makes use of parentheses.

Let it be.

I would also suggest evaluating the actual quality of the question being posed.  If this is all there is to it, I wouldn't bother editing it at *all*; it's a "give me the codes plz" sort of question.